# Polymer core-icon with set not working

Tags: polymer

Don't know if i'm missing something but i'm trying to use a core-icon that is in the "social" set and it's not showing up. I've tried other sets to. The "home" icon is working. Here's what i've got so far.

**EDIT**:
*My directory structure looks like the following.... the flat structure was way to unorganized for me*

```
root/
    /bower_components        
        /polymer
            /bower_components/
                *** Components Here ***
```

**End Edit**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/polymer/bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/bower_components/core-elements/core-elements.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #E5E5E5;
                font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
            }

            core-header-panel {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }

            core-toolbar {
                background: #03a9f4;
                color: white;
            }

            paper-tabs {
                width: 100%;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }

            .container {
                width: 80%;
                margin: 50px auto;
            }

            @media (min-width: 481px) {
                paper-tabs {
                    width: 200px;
                }

                .container {
                    width: 400px;
                }
            }

            core-icon-button {
               position: absolute;
               top: 3px;
               right: 3px;
               fill: #636363;
             }
             :host([favorite]) core-icon-button {
               fill: #da4336;
             }

        </style>
</head>
<body unresolved touch-action="auto">

<core-header-panel>
    <core-toolbar>
        <paper-tabs selected="home" valueattr="name" self-end>
            <paper-tab name="home"><core-icon icon="home"></core-icon> Home</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab name="about"><core-icon icon="social:person"></core-icon> About</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
    </core-toolbar>
</core-header-panel>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an import for the social icons:

`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/iconsets/social-icons.html">`

Comment: This is seriously the easiest fix on the planet. I was so confused because some of the icons from that group worked and some didn't. Thanks for making me less dumb haha!